# Springboot Flux response closed before processing completes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

Hi i have and endpoint that i need to return streaming json array data.
but each item in the array take a some time to process.
Saw that my connection was closed before the streaming completes.

below is my code,

```
@GetMapping("/testStreamingJson", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
fun TestingKS(): Flux<DataClass> {

    var list = ArrayList<String>()
    for (i in 1..100) {
        list.add(i.toString())
    }
    return Flux.fromIterable(list).map {
        DataClass(1, Date()).startProcessing()
    }

}

data class DataClass (
    var data: Int,
    var date: Date
) {
    fun startProcessing(): DataClass {
        Thread.sleep(100) //sleep to simulate take a while for processing to complete
        println(Date())
        return this
    }
}
```

below is the postman response. There is a "connection closed" before 100 items finished processing.

[image]